# how to choose parallel computing framework for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, parallel-processing

how to choose parallel computing framework for machine learning? I am a beginner, I saw there are Spark,Hadoop, OpenMP...what should I consider besides the language?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look up Horovod from Uber, it's specifically designed for machine learning, available for several frameworks such as tensorflow/pytorch. It's available in Docker image repository on AWS too.